# Why does this python datetime format not convert the string of the same format into a datetime object successfully?

Tags: python-3.x, string, datetime, iso8601

```
import datetime as dt

time_str = '2022-02-25 18:37:46.594385+00:00'
```

Then I try to convert this into a datetime object as follows:

```
dt.datetime.strptime(time_str,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z')
```

However it results in the following error:

```
ValueError: time data '2022-02-25 18:37:46.594385+00:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z'
```

The error appears to be coming from the %z section of the format, but overall I do not understand why this is not working, since it seems the specified format does match the string format.  If you could help identify any issues and suggest a solution to convert the example time_str into a datetime object successfully.  Thanks!

Comment: which Python version are you using? Note the [technical details](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#technical-detail): `%z` can only parse colon-separated UTC offset (hh:mm) with version 3.7 or higher.

Comment: see [How do I parse an ISO 8601-formatted date?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/127803/10197418) for other options.

Comment: Python 3.6.3.  So ok, understood.